# FLTK: Fl_Value_Input subclass does not receive FL_KEYDOWN events (only FL_KEYUP)

Tags: fltk

I subclassed `FL_Value_Input` such that I can give the widget a color when it is modified, but the user has not yet pressed enter.

The silly thing is that the `handle(int e)` function is never invoked in case the event is a `FL_KEYDOWN`  event, other events (such as `FL_KEYUP`, `FL_DRAG`, `FL_FOCUS` etc) are being propagated fine.

The widget is part of a widget hierarchy... Could it be that one of its parents in this hierarchy is absorbing this specific `FL_KEYDOWN` event?

EDIT: apparently, the widget also doesn't have focus (tested by comparing `this` to `Fl::focus()`), which is odd, as I am typing into it.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Fx_Value_Input::Fx_Value_Input(int x, int y, int w, int h, const char* l)
: Fl_Value_Input(x, y, w, h, l)
{}

int Fx_Value_Input::handle(int e)
{
    int r = Fl_Value_Input::handle(e);

    if (e == FL_KEYBOARD)
    {
            if ((Fl::event_key() != FL_Enter && Fl::event_key() != FL_KP_Enter ) )
                    color(Fx::get_modified_color());
            else if ((Fl::event_key() == FL_Enter || Fl::event_key() == FL_KP_Enter) &&             color() == Fx::get_modified_color())
                    color(FL_WHITE);
            redraw();
        }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, turns out that Fl_Value_Input is not an Fl_Input, but contains an Fl_Input as a member (encapsulation). This particular member receives and handles the FL_KEYDOWN event and has the focus... I need to find a way that it propagates the FL_KEYDOWN  to Fl_Value_Input ...

Answer (score 1):

Using FL_KEYDOWN is the Windows way of doing things, which, as you have found, doesn't work because you need to subclass Fl_Input_: not Fl_Input and even then, it doesn't work properly.

Instead, use when(FL_WHEN_CHANGED|FL_WHEN_ENTER_KEY).  Check changed() when keys are pressed and clear_changed().  It isn't set when the enter key is pressed.  You can change colours back when that condition is met.

```
inputkey = new Fl_Input...
inputkey->when(FL_WHEN_CHANGED| FL_WHEN_ENTER_KEY);
inputkey->callback(cb);
....

void cb(Fl_Widget *ob)
{
   Fl_Input* ip = dynamic_cast<Fl_Input*>(ob);
   if (ip->changed())
   {
       // change colour
       ip->clear_changed();
   }
   else
   {
      // change colour
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a reply on the [FLTK Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fltkgeneral/rLI_yEHMTYY), explaining the issue... There is no easy workaround for this...

> FLTK delivers key strokes directly to the focus widget. Fl_Value_Input
>   *includes* an Fl_Input widget, and that widget becomes the focus widget when you click in the input field.
>
> Hence the "parent" Fl_Value_Input never sees the Fl_KEYDOWN events.
>   Note  that I quoted "parent" because Fl_Value_Input is a *very*
>   special case.  It's not derived from Fl_Group, but it behaves somewhat
>   like an Fl_Group  widget.
>
> So why does your derived widget get FL_KEYUP events? That's another 
>   feature of FLTK: FL_KEYUP events are also delivered to the focus
>   widget  in the first place. However, AFAICT no core FLTK widget
>   handles FL_KEYUP  events - they all return 0 in their handle()
>   methods. If the focus  widget doesn't handle an event FLTK tries to
>   deliver it to the parent  widget and then up through the widget
>   hierarchy until it reaches the top  level window. Hence (and this *is*
>   IMHO weird) eventually all widgets  will receive all FL_KEYUP events
>   unless one widget returns 1 from its  handle() method (which is
>   usually not the case). Depending on the depth  of the focus widget in
>   the total widget hierarchy it may be that some  widgets get the same
>   FL_KEYUP event multiple times, because all parent  groups of the focus
>   widget try to deliver the event to all their children.